# raw binary stream for dieharder using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine python number generator with dieharder, I found out that it can be done using pipe in linux

```
python3 generator.py | dieharder -a -g 200
```

`-g 200` means that I will use `stdin_input_raw`

here is specification from dieharder manual:

```
Raw binary input reads 32 bit increments of the specified data 
stream. stdin_input_raw accepts a pipe from a raw binary stream.
```

now I created some python code using radom generator:

```
while True:
    sys.stdout.write("{0:b}".format(random.randint(0, 256)))
```

but I think it's not working as expected since the result of terminal command above for first test is:

```
     test_name   |ntup| tsamples |psamples|  p-value |Assessment 
#====================================================================#
diehard_birthdays|   0|       100|     100|0.00000000|  FAILED
```

while for command:

```
cat /dev/urandom | dieharder -a -g 200
```

it is:

```
     test_name   |ntup| tsamples |psamples|  p-value |Assessment
#====================================================================#
diehard_birthdays|   0|       100|     100|0.92477826|  PASSED
```

I suspect that my code for generating `raw input stream` is not correct, how to create this stream in python?

Solution:

```
while True:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('>I', random.randint(0, 2**32)))
```

Comment: From the documentation, it states: "presumed to be a binary stream of 32 bit unsigned integers". That is definitely not what you are writing to standard output. You are writing a bunch of *string representations in base-two format* of *python integers* to the output stream. You are going to want to look into the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to work with raw binary streams easily. Note, python `int` objects *are not primitive numeric types*. They are arbitrary-sized integers, and they are objects.

Comment: thank you for hint, what do you think about that code:

    `while True:
       sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('>i', (random.randint(0, 256))))`

it still not working

Comment: ok I think the one above is actually working, could you please add your answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: You need to use an unsigned 32 bit integer. `i` is signed. Use `I`

Comment: thank you working as expected

Comment: I'm at work, i can write up an answer later, or you can write and accept your own answer